# spring mvc - how to specify file size in HttpServletResponse setHeader method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, download

I have a download action in my spring mvc application. i have `HttpServletResponse response` as an action's parameter and have this line in the body:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "."+file.getExtension()+"\"");
```

when the browser start to download a file, show me `Unknown time remaining`, because the browser doesn't know file size. how can i specify file size in the `setHeader` method?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to specify length in the header?

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length",...)
```

Comment: what is the second argument? the file size? can you explain me more?

Comment: Yes, the second parameter is the fize size:response.setHeader("Content-Length", ""+file.getSize()); Thanks you very much for your replay